# How to set hyperlink to current request path in (intractive report) Fastreport.NET in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fastreport

I use Fastreport.NET (Core) and create a interactive report with hyperlink to another page (at the same report) and it is work in designer but it isn't work on web ( ASP.NET Core - MVC) .
Actually first page hyperlink refer to "localhost:51154/#" instead of "localhost:51154/Admin/FastWage#"

How can i solve it?

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Comment: @HakimehMordadi
thank you
i create an Interactive web report in MVC according to [https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/135/show/](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/135/show/)  but in ASP.NET CORE and when click on hyperlink redirect to root (localhost:51154/#) instead of current url with # at the ended (localhost:51154/Admin/FastWage#) and the fast-report official forum dont explain how change (or add) the middleware to change fastreport web viewer hyperlinks to current url lik as [https://www.fast-report.com:2018/4](https://www.fast-report.com:2018/4)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved
in view (_Layout.cshtml) the front-end developer used

```
<base href="../../../">
```

and because of that the hypelink change to localhost